# MySQL php PDO Select Statement not querying properly

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have a simple SELECT query that is not working properly. It queries all entries where `IS_VISIBLE = 1`. In my table "sections", I currently have 3 records that indicate `IS_VISIBLE = 1` but my page is only pulling 2 records

PHP code:

```
<?php

  date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
  $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=********;charset=utf8";
  $uname = "root";
  $pword = "";

  $db = null;
  $limit = 10;
  $counter = 0;

   while (true) {
   try {
      $db = new PDO($dsn, $uname, $pword);
      $db->exec( "SET CHARACTER SET utf8" );
      $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ); 
      $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true );
      break;
   }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $db = null;
        $counter++;
        if ($counter == $limit)
            throw $e;
    }
} 


   $result = $db->prepare("SELECT PATH FROM `sections` WHERE IS_VISIBLE = 1");
   $result->execute();
       while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
           $path_file=$row["PATH"];
           echo include($path_file);
       }

?>
```

HERE'S A VIEW OF MY TABLE "sections" where you can see there are 3 records where `IS_VISIBLE = 1` but my code only pulls `intro_video.php` and `blog_widget.php` but not `contacts.php`:

[image]

Comment: Contacts php may have an error, not exist, not be in the same directory, or it may be a browser caching thing if you ran this before changing the data in the db.

Comment: Why echo include and not use directly the variable?

Comment: @Mihai - CMS control to hide or display sections within the page. No need to provide HTML for all sections and then hide the ones you don't need - easier for php to only write the HTML code for the ones it needs.

Comment: @developerwjk - I confirmed `contacts.php` is in the correct path - in the same path as `intro_video.php` and `blog_widget.php`

Comment: If you echo `$result->rowCount()`, what does it say then?

Comment: Add another row `IS_VISIBLE = 1`.How many does it echo?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews nothing - same thing... I did find something interesting from another SO post - if I use `echo file_get_contents($path_file)` then all files show up BUT it also shows me all the php code inside each section (as if the php code didn't execute)

Comment: Weird...So i changed the query to `("SELECT * FROM sections")` and these show up: `intro_video.php` `about.php` `services.php` and `testimonials.php` and thats it...

Comment: @Mihai - I just tried that lol, still nothing. And I also included an extra record like you said.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I get no errors - but that does present something interesting - within those sections I am also making sql queries to the same database so I wonder if that is what is stopping the cycle. Basically I start this while loop and when it includes a file, then the php inside that file starts a new sql query having a sql query inside a sql query...thats probably it.